# U2NETDK VisualStudio 2010 add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, universe, u2netdk

Is there any Visual Studio 2010 add-in available for Rocket U2 .NET Database Provider (Universe)? I know there is a tool for 2008 but I can't get this new U2 .NET tool Kit working and generate an ERM.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is: yes there is.

Both the .NET Toolkit and UniObjects for .NET should work seamlessly with VS 2010.

You can download the necessary software from the [Rocket U2](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2) website under "resources/downloads"

You can also use UniObjects for .NET which is available in the "u2-Clients" download on the Rocket website. This is a DLL which you then add as a reference in your Visual Studio project and makes it possible to interact with your UniVerse database and data. The documentation on how to use both products is also available there for download.

If this does not help, ask a more specific question stating the exact error messages you are getting, together with details of which .NET framework version you are using and UniVerse platform and version.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to inform you that U2NETDK V 1.2.0 will have new product called U2 Database Add-ins for Visual Studio. It will allow you Server Explorer Integration that simplifies U2 data access in .NET. You will see U2 Tables, Views and Subroutines in Server Explorer and you can drag and drop in Designer such as DataSet Designer / Entity Data Model Designer. We will go EAP soon.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing, I want to add that you do not need any more 'UniObjects for .NET' as this functionality is added into 'U2 Toolkit for .NET' Product. We have sample code in the installation that demonstrates 'UniObjects for .NET' functionality.